# Hide radio field with css when no access to html

Tags: css

I have this html:

```
<input id="color_#DADAD2" type="radio" value="#DADAD2" name="color">
<input id="color_#FFA4A4" type="radio" value="#FFA4A4" name="color">
```

and I want hide these fields with css. I tried several method such

```
#color_#DADAD2, #color_#FFA4A4 {display: none;}
```

OR

```
#color_#DADAD2, #color_#FFA4A4 input[type="radio"] {display: none;}
```

but none of them work and fields still displayed.

I seen also these input seem to be controlled by another style:

```
form input {
height: 18px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
padding-top: 2px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please note 2 points:

1) I don't have access to html (because is an external web software not controlled by myself) but I'm allowed to put css code inside a dedicated css file.

2) I'm a css newbie

any clue please ?

Comment: Is there other CSS applied to this radio buttons?

Comment: #color_#DADAD2, #color_#FFA4A4 { display:none !important } - i woulden recomend important but i should override whatever css there should be appliede to the radio btns before your style.

Comment: @Nopzen: I tried "important" but this don't work...and Yes some other CSS seem to be apply. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [*escape*](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) the hash (`#`) characters within your CSS selectors using backslashes `\`:

```css
#color_\#DADAD2, #color_\#FFA4A4 {display: none;}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcGSz/).

Comment: you rock this work well !! I did not know it was necessary to use backslashes in this case. Many thank.